# Клавиатура перекрывает EditText

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-edittext, клавиатура

Есть ViewPager, на двух соседних страницах на одной высоте расположены два EditText - ввод номера телефона и проверочный код. Задача - при заходе на первую страницу встать на поле ввода номера и открыть клавиатуру. После ввода данных и нажатия Done, не закрывая клавиатуру, перейти на следующую страницу и встать на второе поле ввода.

Реализовано так:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/verification"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/superup_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="33%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="65%"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/animated_superup_logo_white"/>

    <superup.onboarding.NonSwipeableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/verifyPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/transition">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/superup_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="67%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/superup_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/superup_name"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/layout_start_text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/layout_number_text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="3%"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent="23%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="75%">

                <superup.onboarding.CountryCodePicker
                    android:id="@+id/country_code"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:contentColor="@color/white"
                    app:countryPreference="IL"
                    app:defaultNameCode="IL"
                    app:hideNameCode="true"
                    app:textSize="24sp"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:digits="1234567890"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_otp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <superup.onboarding.PinEntryEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_code"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:digits="1234567890"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent="23%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="20%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="20%"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_wrong"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/et_code"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/wrong_number"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txt_wrong"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    </superup.onboarding.NonSwipeableViewPager>

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

```
verifyPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            int lastPosition = 0;

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                //rotate logo on scroll between page 0-1
                if (position < 1) {
                    superup_logo.setTranslationY(0);
                    superup_logo.setRotation(positionOffset * 90);

                    //remove delayed scroll on user swipe
                    if (positionOffset > 0)
                        removeCallbacks(handler, runnable);

                }

                //move logo up on scroll between page 1-2
                else if (position < 2) {
                    superup_logo.setRotation(90f);
                    superup_logo.setTranslationY(-getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 2 * positionOffset);
                }

                //move logo down on scroll between page 2-3
                else if (position < 3) {
                    float begin = superup_logo.getTop() - getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 2;
                    float end = (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - superup_logo.getMeasuredHeight()) / 2;

                    superup_logo.setY(begin + (end - begin) * positionOffset);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                switch (position) {

                    case 0:
                        hideKeyboard();
                        setFirstPage(delay);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        keyHandler = new Handler();
                        keyRunnable = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                et_number.setSelection(et_number.getText().length()); // set cursor at the end
                                showKeyboard(et_number); //open keyboard
                            }
                        };
                        keyHandler.postDelayed(keyRunnable, 1500); // 1500 ms delay
                        verifyPager.setPagingEnabled(false); // disable page swipe
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        et_code.setSelection(et_code.getText().length());
                        showKeyboard(et_code);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        hideKeyboard();

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            //start the logo blink animation
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Drawable animation = superup_logo.getDrawable();
                                    if (animation instanceof Animatable) {
                                        ((Animatable) animation).start();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 300);
                        }

                        //start logo scale down and the background animation
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) verifyPager.getBackground();
                                Animation animationScaleDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.scale_down);
                                superup_logo.startAnimation(animationScaleDown);
                                transition.startTransition(500);

                                animationScaleDown.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                                        // open another activity

                                        SuperupApplication.getPlatformsManager().setLoginData(
                                                ObservableContactsBook.formatPhoneNumber(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(txt_number.getText())));
                                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PlatformsActivity.class));
                                        finish();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                        break;
                }

                lastPosition = position;

            }

            /**
             * Remove 1500 ms delay for keyboard appearance (from page 1)
             * and hide keyboard
             *
             * @param state int PageScrollState
             */
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                // remove show keyboard delay handler
                if (state == verifyPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                    removeCallbacks(keyHandler, keyRunnable);
                }
            }
        });
```

При переходе на вторую страницу по нажатию Done второй EditText оказывается под клавиатурой.

```
    et_number.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            switch (actionId) {
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                    verifyPager.setCurrentItem(verifyPager.getChildCount() - 1);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Все это проявляется на Самсунге с Android 6. На Nexus, китайцах все ок. День потратил на поиски решения, пока безуспешно. Может можно как-то иначе программно сделать свайп?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы `EditText` кликался при старте активности добавьте в него тэг
 `</requestFocus>`:

```
<EditText
  ...
  ...>
  </requestFocus>
</EditText>
```

Или в коде `Java`

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Если клавиатура закрввает ваш `View` то добавьте в тэг активности в `AndroidManifest`

```
<activity
    ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
</activity>
```

Зависит от ситуации, но мне кажется вам подойдет `adjustPan`, на всякий случай вот вам на заметку

`adjustResize` - размеры компонентов в окне активности могут изменяться, чтобы освободить место для экранной клавиатуры.

`adjustPan` - окно активности и его компоненты не изменяются, а сдвигаются таким образом, чтобы текстовое поле с фокусом не было закрыто клавиатурой.

**Насчет программного свайпа**

Это, конечно, бред :D Но можно обернуть 2 `EditText` в `ScrollView` и при нажатии на `Done` делать так

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
}
});
```